# Displaying Stack name as legend key

Tags: highcharts

Using a stacked bar at the moment to display "Attended" and "Unattended" along with `linkedTo:previous` to group the legends together... but the legend is showing "unattended" I want these groups to be called "Location 1" "Location 2" etc. I was thinking I could perhaps use:

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.options.stack + '</b><br/>' +
                this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
        }
    },
    legend: {
        labelFormatter: function () {
            return this.series.options.stack;
        }
    },
```

However I get the error `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined"` I assume as the legend is seeing the series when calling `this` rather than the stack?

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/uk5jakL6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Legend should be

```
legend: {
    labelFormatter: function () {
        return this.userOptions.stack
    }
},
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uk5jakL6/) demo